# Elegant way to show corresponding text_field_tag value in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So my problem is showing something that a model has in a nice and simpler way.

So what currently works?

In my viewer this works fine:

```
<%= text_field_tag(:first_name, (current_user.present? ? current_user : '').first_name.present? ? current_user.first_name : '') %>
```

However this is too long and really hard to maintain, especially when I have several more fields.

So to avoid that I made this in my controller

```
def user_vals(value)
    if(current_user.present?)
      current_user.value.present? ? current_user.value : ''
    end
    return ''
  end
```

Within this controller I can call `user_vals(:first_name)` but get `undefined method`value'` error. Furthermore I cannot just call

```
<%= text_field_tag(:first_name, @user_vals(:first_name)) %>
```

As I am getting some syntax error with brackets but that's not the real issue.

So my ultimate goal is to have something like this:

```
<%= text_field_tag(:first_name, @user_vals(:first_name)) %>
```

Rather than the first code I've given above. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What is the intent of ```@profile_vals```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try` in this case. Just write:

```
<%= text_field_tag(:first_name, current_user.try(:first_name)) %>
```

See: http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

Comment: Works just as expected. Do you know if I can do the same thing from another method (ie still use `user_vals` method and pass the `:first_name` parameter)? If so could you give an example please?

Comment: @SarpKaya : You can use `try` when you want to call a method on an instance that might be `nil`. See link to the documentation in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to take a step back and try to use Duck Typing to solve this...

What you have right now is a `current_user` method. This method can return whatever object it wants if the user is not logged in, and that object can respond to whatever it wants. Here's a simplified example:

```
def current_user
  @user || OpenStruct.new(first_name: "")
end
```

Note: I'm assuming `@user` holds the currently-signed in user... but this may be a call to `super` instead, or whatever else depending on your implementation.

So now, instead of branching based on what *type* of object is coming back from the `current_user` method, you can now just use the returned object without regard.

```
current_user.first_name # => Either the User object's first name or `""`
```

You can go further with this by creating e.g. a GuestUser class and having `GuestUser.new` returned instead of the `OpenStruct` above. Guestuser would be a model that is not data-base backed and could respond to any number of methods as needed.

This idea has been represented by many others as well. And using a class to prevent repeated code switching based on nil actually has a name: The Special Case Pattern. As a quick, free example, see the [Guest User RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record). Or, if you subscribe to Ruby Tapas, be sure to check out episode [112: Special Case](http://www.rubytapas.com/episodes/112-Special-Case). This topic, and many others, are also covered in depth in Avdi Grimm's excellent book: [Confident Ruby](http://www.confidentruby.com/), which I highly recommend.